# jQgrid delete id return row id

Tags: php, jqgrid

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myDataList").jqGrid({
                url: "<?= base_url(); ?>getmydata/getCategory",
                datatype: "json",
                autowidth: true,
                mtype: "GET",
                colNames: ["Category", "Description", ""],
                colModel: [
                    {name: "c_category", editable: true, width: 1},
                    {name: "c_description", editable: true, width: 4, edittype: 'textarea'},
                    {name: "categoryid", key: true, editable: true, hidden: true, editrules: {edithidden: false}}
                ],
                pager: "#myDataListPager",
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                sortname: "c_category",
                sortorder: "asc",
                height: 'auto',
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                caption: "",
                editurl: "<?= base_url(); ?>getmydata/c_action"
            });
            jQuery("#myDataList").jqGrid('navGrid', '#myDataListPager', {add: true, edit: true, del: true, search: true},
            {closeAfterEdit: true}, {closeAfterAdd: true}, {
                beforeShowForm: function($form) {
                    $("td.delmsg", $form[0]).html("Do you want to delete the row with <b>id=" +
                            $("#myDataList").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow') + "</b>?");
                },
                afterSubmit: function(response) {
                    response = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                    alert(response.error);
                    if (response.error == 0) {
                        $.openDialog("info", "Successfully deleted ");
                    } else {
                        showDialog($('#Dialog'), response.msg, "An error occured");
                    }
                }}
            );
        });
```

Above is my grid code, When I click delete the id is the rowid instead of the categoryid, how can I set the id to categoryid instead of row id. I would like to show a dialog message if the response.error is true. When I alert the response.error, I can get the correct result, but I don't know how to call the dialog to display.

http://mymoney.webege.com/getmydata/getCategory?_search=false&nd=1408865724728&rows=10&page=1&sidx=c_category&sord=asc <--  this is the URL I get the json data.

Above is my return json, and I check when click the delete the id is the row id in sequence.

[image]

Comment: use jsfiddel will help us understand

Comment: the JSON data from the URL which you posted contains both `id` and `categoryid` and both have the same value. It's unclear what `categoryid` value you expect and what rowid will be sent instead. Could you provide an example? For example if one delete the item with `id=7` you should get `7` posted during Delete operation.

Comment: But in the grid table the id is in sequence instead of what the json return. In the json the id sequnce is 5 11 6 9 ... but in grid the sequence is 1 2 3 4 .....

Answer (score 0):

You use `key: true` for the column `"categoryid"`. So the values of rowid and `categoryid` have to be identical. You should post an example of testdata which can be used to reproduce the problem or you can debug the code yourself to understand *why* rowid and `categoryid` are different in your case.

You second problem with `afterSubmit` is easy to solve. You should don't show any dialogs inside of `afterSubmit`. Instead of that you should just return the required information in the correct format. `afterSubmit` of form editing have to return **array of up to 3 items**. In case of Delete operation if could be up to 2 items. If no error take place then you should return `[true]`. In case of error you should return `[false, "error description"]`. If your case it would be something like below

```js
afterSubmit: function (response) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
    return (data != null && data.error !== 0) ? [false, data.msg] : [true];
}
```

Comment: If I sort the data to ascending order will that affected?

Comment: @user3687053: You don't use `loadonce: true`. So the sorting will just makes one more request to the server with corresponding `sidx` and `sord` parameter. The server makes the sorting and returns the sorted data. jqGrid just refill the grid with absolutely new data. If you correctly fill the data you will have no problem.

Comment: I add in loadonce:true still the same the rowid still in sequence

Comment: @user3687053: By the way you can **remove hidden "categoryid"**  from the `colModel` and simplify the format of data returned by the server. For example the `{ "id": "10", "cell": ["Medical", "", "10"]}` can be changed to `{ ["Medical", "", "10"]}`. One need to add `jsonReader: {cell: "", id: 2}` parameter to jqGrid to be able to read the new format of data and correctly fill rowid.

Comment: Possible to pass in id or set the id when click delete?

Comment: @user3687053: I didn't suggested you to use `loadonce:true`. I just wrote that sorting could be not an issue. **The server** make the sorting. Do you sure that the value of `categoryid` column is correct? It contains the values like 1, 10, 7 ...

Comment: I have attached a picture to explain my problem, the categoryid is correct, when I click delete on row 5, i should delete record with categoryid = 15, but the $_POST['id'] return me 5. Possible to set the id to 15.

Comment: @user3687053: The JSON data which you send contains `5` (!!!) and not `15` for the item having id=5. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user3687053.htm) reproduces the test with *your* data. If one try to delete first row having id=5 you will see in HTTP trace that correct data `oper=del&id=5` will be posted to the server (not id=1 like you wrote before).

Comment: @user3687053: The JSON data from the URL which you posted contains `5` and not 16 or 15: `{ "id": "5", "cell": ["Accomodation", "Nothing like a roof over your head. This one is important too, and make sure that you can afford whatever dwelling you choose!", "5"] }`. Just open [the URL](http://mymoney.webege.com/getmydata/getCategory?_search=false&nd=1408865724728&rows=10&page=1&sidx=c_category&sord=asc) and verify it.

Comment: As you can see, for your id there is not in sequence, so the delete is correct,

Comment: @user3687053: I used only the code and the data which you posted. I suppose that you work not with the code/data which you posted.

Comment: That is because I want to show you all the data, so I host it to free hosting, the screen shot is the local.

Comment: Had updated the screen shot which run from server instead of local.

Comment: @user3687053: Sorry, but the goal of stackoverflow is not that sombody debug your code for free. One post descriptions of problem **which could have another people**. By sharing of description of the problems and the ways to solve it **one can help many other people**. It's the goal. I think that you have now enough information to verify in your code. You can carefully compare my demo with youth and I'm sure that you will find the reason of your problem very quickly. The reason will be in the part of the code which you not posted here. Some small thing probably

Comment: The only part that my code different from you is the url and the afterSubmit, I haven't upload the changes on afterSubmit to server.